# How to iterate through Operators in LLVM IR instruction

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I have the following llvm instruction:

```
  %or = or i32 shl (i32 1, i32 urem (i32 ptrtoint ([4 x %struct.my_struct1]* getelementptr inbounds (%struct.my_struct2, %struct.my_struct3* null, i32 0, i32 18, i32 48, i32 3) to i32), i32 32)), %add, !dbg !278709
```

And I need to iterate over all of the operators.

1) Is there a pass (or a flag for clang) which can spilt this instruction?

2) how do I iterate over these operators in a simple way?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `for(auto & i : x->getParent()->getInstList()) { ... }` do what you want? Or if you want to use names and separate lines per instruction, `...{ i.setName("foo" + utostr(n++)); }`.

Comment: I dont think so, since llvm recognize only %or as an instruction while the other operators are not.